# ASP.NET hosting in Europe

Tags: asp.net, hosting

I am looking for a hosting company that can host my couple webpages written with ASP.NET.

I just found out my home country does not have any hosts for it so I would like to find a reputable host with good prices and uptime in Europe.

Comment: Here is the list http://www.microsoft.com/web/hosting/home

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have experiance with Hosteurope (hosteurope.com) and 1&1 (http://order.1and1.co.uk). Hosteurope has a good service but the servers are to old and slow. 1&1 has good vserver and they are fast and has good technique.

But an official ms page can show you more hosts: http://www.microsoft.com/web/hosting/home

[Now moved here](http://www.asp.net/hosting/home)

Comment: I sent a email to 1on1 and hopefully I can move my domains there. Looks like they are exactly what I am looking for. Will accept this answer, thanks.